# Laravel 5.1 What's the difference of lockForUpdate in DB builder and Eloquent?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

Using lockForUpdate on Eloquent seems not always working.

```
       DB::beginTransaction();
       User::find(1)->lockForUpdate();
       ... (doing some logic)
       DB::commit();
```

But using

```
DB::table('users')->where('id', '=', $userId)->lockForUpdate()
```

always works. What's the differences between those two lockForUpdate()?

- Laravel Version: 5.1
- PHP Version: 5.7
- Database Driver & Version: MySQL 14.14

Comment: Looks like interesting question. However, what do you mean exactly by *it works* and *it doesn't work*? Please explain expected/unexpected behaviors and errors messages if any.

Comment: @alariva, in my case, I tried to create a unique entry in user profile table by each user. If the user accidentally to click 'Save' button twice (it didn't prevent the user to trigger many clicks), it will create two rows in user profile table with User::find(1)->lockForUpdate();. So I think it didn't lock correctly. Does it make any sense?

Comment: Now I see, but it doesn't has to do with locking rows, exactly. On the other hand, taking care of just the users table does not save you from the same issue on other tables. I myself have [the exact same problem (still unsolved) in my project.](https://github.com/timegridio/timegrid/issues/20) Good news are, you can do something at least for the `users` table.

Comment: So what you could do is making `unique()` the *email* or *username* field of your `users` table in your migration file. Here [an example](https://github.com/timegridio/timegrid/blob/master/database/migrations/2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php#L17)

Answer (score -1):

```
User::lockForUpdate()->find(1);
```

this would be work

`find()` will return a Model not a query Builder.

`lockForUpdate()` is a method from query Builder